# Oracle SQL - join two tables with columns in different order

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't know if I asked the right question and if it is 
unnecessary. The question is about SELECT if I have 2 tables with this columns for example:

Table 1:

```
a   b   c
---------
```

Table 2:

```
d   e   f  g  h
----------------
```

Can I join that two tables but not one after the other?
For example:

```
a  d  b  c  e  f
----------------
```

without writing column names manually?

```
select a, d, b, c, e, f from...
```

Comment: you can't do it without writing column name

Comment: Why does column order matter? It's unusual in a RDBMS.

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: SQL by intent and design works with column names. So NO there is not a way to avoid naming the relevant columns in the join predicate. Well that's not completely true  you can do a cross join which results in every row matched with every row of the other.

Answer (score 0):

For these tables:

```sql
create table A (c1 integer, c2 integer)
/
create table B (c3 integer, c3 integer)
```

`select a.*, b.* from A a, B b` returns columns c1, c2, c3, c4

`select b.*, a.* from A a, B b` returns columns c3, c4, c1, c2

Otherwise you have to write columns manually.